# Kotlin is there anything that is not a subtype of Any

Tags: generics, types, kotlin

Given the following code:

```
fun <T> getClass(instance: T): Class<T>
{
     return instance.javaClass
}
```

I simply have a function that has a type parameter and a variable of that type.

I want to get the class of that instance, so I call .javaClass

The issue is that the above code gives a compiler error because .javaClass can only be done on instances of Any and T is not a subtype of Any

The way to fix this would be to have the generic type T be replaced by T : Any, but this adds quite some noise

Nullability (aka Any?) might be the reason, but I am unsure of if this is true and if so, why.

So, the question is, is there anything that is not a subtype of Any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Any?` is not a subtype of `Any`, because not every valid value of type `Any?` is a valid value of type `Any`.

Without the `T : Any` restriction, you could call your function as, for example:

```
val x = getClass<Any?>(null)
```

...which would crash at runtime, so Kotlin doesn't allow this code to compile.

Comment: Since i avoid all cases of nullability, would I have to place T : Any on all methods that use generics (where there is currently no upper bound)?

Comment: Yes, you need to add this constraint for all functions where you need the value of a type parameter to be non-null. Note that "avoiding all cases of nullability" is not an idiomatic use of Kotlin; what Kotlin allows you to do is to make clear which values can be null, and to handle them safely.

Comment: ofcourse, nulls make sense in some cases, just not where I use it... in any case, i'll be refactoring my code for the next few hours : ( ... thanks a bunch ; )

Comment: @yole how is that possible that Nothing is subclass of Any? For me it looks like Nothing is not subclass of anything and nothing can subclass Nothing. Looks like it's just separate entity in class graph.

Comment: @asm0dey, just like an empty set is a subset of any other set, `Nothing` is a subtype of all other types because for any type `Foo` all instances of `Nothing` (which are none, though) are also instances of `Foo`.

Comment: @asm0dey, because `Nothing` is a subtype of all classes, you can always assign/pass/return an expression of type `Nothing` to any type.  For example, throwing an exception is an expression of type `Nothing`, so I can do things like: `fun myFail(): Nothing = throw RuntimeException()` and `val myStr: String = nullableStr ?: myFail()`.  Because `myFail` returns `Nothing` and `Nothing` is a subtype of `String`, the `Nothing` expression is valid on the right side of the assignment.